# Primefaces 7 executeScript() not invoking javascript functions in ajax requests

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

I have this little project with primefaces 7. 
It show a table with some data and in each row a button open a dialog to modify the item.
Everything works fine except when i try to close the dialog and reload the grid within the save method of the modify bean.

For some reason I can't understand, the code
`PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("closeModifyDialog(); reloadGrid();");`
doesn't work at all, no error in the eclipse console nor in the browser.

I tried to put it somewhere else `PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("alert('peek-a-boo')");` and it **only** works if I put it in the constructor of the bean of the list (which is also the first bean loaded when you open the site, a non ajax request )

If you need something else ask me, i'm stuck with this thing, where I'm wrong?

### itemsList.xhtml

```
        <h:form id="itemsListForm">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagesPanel" styleClass="mrm-overflow-messages">
                <p:messages for="#{itemsListBean.infoMessagesBox}" closable="true" />
                <p:messages for="#{itemsListBean.errorMessagesBox}" closable="true" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:remoteCommand name="**reloadGrid**"
                actionListener="#{itemsListBean.onSearch()}"
                update="@form:accordionPanel:itemsDataTable" />
            <p:remoteCommand name="updateMessages" update="@form:messagesPanel" />

            <p:remoteCommand name="**closeModifyDialog**"
                action="PF('modifyItemDialog').hide()" update="modifyItemDialog" />

            <p:accordionPanel id="accordionPanel"
                styleClass="items-list-accordion" multiple="true" activeIndex="0,1">
                <!-- FILTRI -->
                <p:tab title="#{defaultBundle.filters}">
                </p:tab>

                <!-- TABELLA -->
                <p:tab title="#{defaultBundle.assets}">
                    <p:dataTable id="itemsDataTable" value="#{itemsListBean.items}"
                        var="item" rows="10" paginator="true"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 50, 100" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                        styleClass="items-list-datatable">
                        <p:column style="width: 5%; text-align: center;">
                            <p:commandButton value="Mod"
                                actionListener="#{itemsListBean.modifyItem(item)}"
                                oncomplete="PF('modifyItemDialog').show();" />
                        </p:column>

                         [...]
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>
            </p:accordionPanel>

            <h:panelGroup id="modifyItemDialogParent">
                <p:dialog id="modifyItemDialog" widgetVar="modifyItemDialog"
                    header="#{defaultBundle.asset}" modal="true" resizable="false"
                    closable="true" draggable="true" position="center"
                    showEffect="fade" onShow="initDialog();" hideEffect="fade">
                    <ui:include src="xhtml-dialogs/modifyItemDialog.xhtml" />
                </p:dialog>

                <p:remoteCommand name="initDialog"
                    actionListener="#{modifyItemBean.init()}"
                    update="@form:modifyItemDialog:modifyItemPanel" />

            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                <p:commandButton value="#{defaultBundle.confirm}"
                    style="float: right;" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" />
                <p:commandButton value="#{defaultBundle.back}" style="float: right;"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
```

### modifyItemDialog.xhtml

```
     <h:panelGroup id="modifyItemPanel" styleClass="modify-item-panel">

        <h:panelGroup id="dialogMmessagesPanel"
            styleClass="mrm-overflow-messages">
            <p:messages for="#{itemsListBean.infoMessagesBox}" closable="true" />
            <p:messages for="#{itemsListBean.errorMessagesBox}" closable="true" />
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputNumber styleClass="input-big" decimalPlaces="0"
                        thousandSeparator="" decimalSeparator=","
                        value="#{modifyItemBean.oldCode}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{defaultBundle.save}"
                        actionListener="#{modifyItemBean.save()}"
                        update="dialogMmessagesPanel">
                        <p:confirm header="#{defaultBundle.save}"
                            message="#{defaultBundle.saveItemMessage}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputNumber styleClass="input-big" decimalPlaces="0"
                        thousandSeparator="" decimalSeparator=","
                        value="#{modifyItemBean.newCode}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
     </h:panelGroup>
```

### ModifyItemBean.java

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "modifyItemBean")
public class ModifyItemBean extends BasicBean {

[...]

public void save() {

        if (validateForm()) {

            switch (mode) {
            case MODIFY:
                item.setCodice(oldCode);
                item.setCodiceNuovo(newCode);
                item.setDescrizione(description);
                item.setBene(asset);
                item.setUbicazione(site);
                item.setFabbricato(building);
                item.setPiano(floor);
                item.setValore(value);
                item.setPresente(present);

                SaveItemEnvelopeIN request = new SaveItemEnvelopeIN();
                request.setItem(item);

                Envelope response = itemsService.mergeItem(request);

                if (response.isSuccessfullyCompleted()) {
                    **PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("closeModifyDialog(); reloadGrid();");**
                    addInfoMessage("ITEM_SAVED_SUCCESSFULLY");
                } else {
                    addErrorMessages(response.getErrors());
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make your question into a [mcve]. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: and also see how the http response looks like... And... I did not downvote (yet) but please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Building a minimal example (that still had the problem), I tried to update the Maven Dependencies from

**com.sun.faces jsf-api 2.0.1

com.sun.faces jsf-impl 2.0.1**

to

**org.glassfish jakarta.faces 2.3.14

javax.enterprise cdi-api 2.0.SP1**

(Thanks to BalusC comment)

and that did the trick.

Comment: That's great, but err 2.1.7 is still from February 2012 .. Over 7 years old!! Why exactly are you picking jurassic versions .. ?? Today's latest available is [org.glassfish:jakarta.faces:2.3.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces/2.3.14)

Comment: Copy/paste is not a great way to do a job right, my fault! I switched to faces in Jakarta (with cdi.api dependency needed) and everything works fine, I update the answer, thanks!